# drupal---a theme can't work with module ajax comments

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, module, themes

i have installed the ajax comments( http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments ) module,and use d the theme http://drupal.org/project/inove . when under IE7,the ajax_comments module can't work. but under Firefox,it's ok. the annoy thing is that when i changed the theme to garland, when under IE7/FF.it's all ok. there must be something wrong with the inove theme. i have checked it time and time again. but can't find how to correct it. hope someone can help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this problem before. The AJAX comments module must collide with some JavaScript in your template, try to disable all JavaScript scripts that included in your theme (in yourtheme.info or in template.php) and check it again - Don't forget to clear cache in Drupal performance page after you disabled the JavaScript.